# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-0-0-1-0-63-0' for key '****', query was: INSERT INTO `mg_catalogrule_product`

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.9

When setting a 'Catalog Price Rule' the targeted items return the following warning on saving from their own product page. It affects both simple and configurable items and the 'Price Rule' still does it's job.

I've truncated all the mg_catalogrule tables apart from the main mg_catalogrule (which won't) as per previous issues with this warning but nothing changes apart from resetting the id numbers.

When setting the rule to inactive the product can be saved without a warning!

Any clues please?

Magento 1.9.2.4

Full Warning Statement:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-0-0-1-0-63-0' for key '4EF1A09B7972968AC381B86C6B948A5E', query was: INSERT INTO `mg_catalogrule_product` (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`action_operator`,`action_amount`,`action_stop`,`sort_order`,`sub_simple_action`,`sub_discount_amount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: It means you are doing something that is trying to insert a row that violates a unique contraint `'6-0-0-1-0-63-0'` in that index named `'4EF1A09B7972968AC381B86C6B948A5E'` . The schema of the table can be seen with `show create table mg_catalogrule_product`

Comment: You spoke early on about truncating stuff. Except for one table that disallowed it. That is most likely because it is the parent (*referenced*) that other tables rely on for Foreign Key constraints. Even if the children are empty, `TRUNCATE` will never work on a parent. So you have to do `DELETE FROM parentTableName` to zao all the rows.